# I am losing unicode characters somewhere (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem with unicode characters getting chomped up a bit. I have a config file that supplies me with the variable `location`. The config file has `# -*- coding utf-8 -*-` at the top but `file -bi config-file-name` tells me the encoding is `us-ascii` and no matter what I do (including `iconv` and `recode` (linux)), it refuses to change that.

Anyway, I retrieve some data with unicode characters in them (passed as `input_data` below) and the data looks fine when I look at it directly. However, somewhere in the following I chew it up:

```
def make_message(input_data):

    messagestring = ''

    if isinstance(input_data, list):
        messagestring = '\n'.join(input_data)

    elif isinstance(input_data, dict):
        for key, val in input_data.items():
            messagestring += key + '\n'
            if isinstance(val, dict):
                for newkey, newval in val.items():
                    messagestring += newkey + ' ' + newval + '\n'
            else:
                messagestring += val + '\n'
    return messagestring
```

Later, I call this in the following way:

```
weather_msg = location + '\n' + make_message(message)
```

I figured that the encoding of my config file (where "location" comes from) is forcing the whole string to turn into ascii, but this is just a guess and in my googling, I can't figure out if that's how things are supposed to work.

I've tried a bunch of stuff, including trying to encode `location` and I've googled character encoding a lot, but I can't get my unicode characters back and I can't figure out where I'm chewing them up.

Can anyone see an obvious mistake I'm making somewhere that forces my unicode data into ascii? Alternately, I could write this all out to a file and then email that if that's the smarter way to do it and if it would solve my encoding problems. The information was short enough that I was just storing it in memory, but I am open to being told that this is a dumb way to do things.

Thanks for reading and for any suggestions.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code than opens, reads, and writes the config file, which is where it sounds like the problem is.

Comment: Also, `messagestring` must be a `str` (meaning Unicode) when you exit that function. What are you seeing that makes you think it isn't?

Comment: I wrote the config file. I haven't coded the part that creates it yet. Also, what you mentioned about messagestring I thought must be truetrue, but I'm getting text that looks like this `Air Temp 66.4 (rectangle question mark)(rectangle question mark)`

Comment: Where are you getting that text? Also, how are you inspecting it? Printing the Unicode string directly with `print`? If so, are your `stdout` and console both UTF-8, or something different? Finally, you still haven't made it clear exactly which values are bad, and at what point they become bad. All you've shown is code that concatenates a bunch of Unicode strings together. If one of them is garbage, of course the concatenated result will be garbage…

Comment: It prints in interactive shell just fine and prints fine when scripted, but when I created my email message it was getting chewed. I was having trouble tracking down the problem, which is why I asked, assuming there was some weird mixture happening with unicode and non-unicode.

I am using the data to send an email to a SMS receiver. I figured out that's where the problem is. Other hosts receive it okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python only respects coding declaration comments in source files, not text files opened as data.

Wherever you open the config file, instead of this:

```
open(config_path)
```

… do this:

```
open(config_path, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: This was a forehead slapper moment for me, because I totally forgot about looking at this. I was using ConfigParser to parse the config file and never officially opened it. When I started Googling, though, it turned out that others have had problems with ConfigParser reading utf-8 (found a handful of threads here on Stack Overflow, in fact). Turns out the problem is with the receiver. All other test addresses to which the data is emailed encode it just fine. That's why I couldn't get any different behavior even though I tried a variety of different "fixes" on my side.

Comment: In that case, it's [`ConfigParser.read`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) that you want to pass a specific encoding to, rather than `open`… but otherwise, same deal. (Unless you're using Python 3.0-3.1 and can't upgrade, in which case you will need to manually `open` the file and pass it to `readfp`.)